# How to decrement the value of Session when a Javascript runs

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui

Actually i am performing a task like dynamic controls generation and when i delete the last created dynamical generated controls by delete button.
I am performing the delete operation using JavaScript.
While I am creating the controls,the session value gets incremented.
Now, I need to decrement the value of session when i perform the delete operation through JavaScript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Session variables are `maintained on server side` and you can not access them on client using javascript. You need to send request to server. You need to do `postback or send ajax` call to change (`decrement`) session variables.

Comment: Is there any alternative for this Scenario?
Actually I am Preparing a Survey Sheet with Questions and Question Numbers need to increase and decrease according to the order.

Answer (score 0):

The only possible way of doing it through JavaScript is to create a method on server that will decrement the value of your Session variable, and then execute that function asynchronously through JavaScript.